# How to rename only specific url through htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I have managed to remove the .php extension using the below htaccess code but the issue i face now is index.php shows like [www.site.com/index](http://www.site.com/index)

could someone help me out to rename it to [www.site.com/home](http://www.site.com/home) instead of /index?

Here is my complete htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ pages.php?$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(css|x?html?|php)$">  
  SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
 ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
 RewriteRule .* index.php [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

Really appreciate your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please use following Rules set in your .htaccess file once. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
##new redirection rules here for index.php to home.
RewriteRule ^index\.php/?$ /home? [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^home/?$ site/index.php [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ pages.php?$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(css|x?html?|php)$">  
  SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
 ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [NC]
 RewriteRule .* index.php [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: In url i see it written home but my dir is localhost/site/index but after updating it goes to localhost/home

Comment: @Ginger, Please try my updated rules now. Considering that you have folder named `site` which is in root alongside with htaccess file. Please do clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. Let me know how it goes.'

Comment: @Ginger, could you please do let me know if my solution has worked for you?